# Design Login and Register page using android tabs

Tags: android

I want to design a  login and register layout using android tabs. Image is as shown below. how do i proceed 
     [image]

Comment: You can proceed by doing this: "File -> New -> Android Project"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Android API Support Library and the sample `FragmentTabsPager` located at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html

You would have two tabs, corresponding to two `Fragments` that you could name RegisterFragment and LoginFragment.

Basically you would remove the lines

```
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
            LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
```

and replace them with

```
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("register").setIndicator("Register"),
           RegisterFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("login").setIndicator("Login"),
           LoginFragment.class, null);
```

Then you implement those Fragments and integrate this code into your Activity.  You'll also need to integrate the fragment_tabs_pager.xml layout into your layout.

Comment: Hi louie, activity part is right.. how can i change tab colors?  default color is gray  and black. i want to change it to blue.. layout color i could change

Comment: To style your tabs, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127446/custom-style-for-androids-tabwidget

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use FrameLayout to do it in a simple way,
managing the visualization when you user press "Register" or "Login".

Something like that:

- TabRow with two buttons those have the same weight (and a selector of
  different colors to manage differents state)
- FrameLayout with two children: one for the registration section and one to allow user to login