# change tabhost color

Tags: android, android-tabhost

How can I change the color of the tiny blue(or dark gray) line on the bottom of the tabhost? Is it possible?

[tabhost http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/802/sc20120607092226.png/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/802/sc20120607092226.png/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post may help you: [Custom style for Android's TabWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4127446/1231943)

It's about changing some styles and themes of tab elements. I imagine what you need to do is set the style for the TabHost like this:

```
<TabWidget
        style="@style/MyTabStyle"
```

You would then define that how you wish inside your styles XML file.

Also, this could be helpful: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136