# Looking for a universal TabHost style that will work on Android, HTC Sense, Samsung, etc. skins

Tags: android, android-tabhost, htcsense

The default style for the Android TabHost works fine for straight Android systems.  However, on HTC Sense, they use dark text on a dark background, which is unreadable.

[image: TabHost from HTC Sense UI]

What's the easiest way to have a TabHost that has visible text across all the various flavors of android skins?  I would prefer to not have to make a completely custom look-and-feel if possible.

My targetSDK is 10 and my minSDK is 7.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127446/custom-style-for-androids-tabwidget and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647821/android-highlighted-tab-of-tabwidget-not-readable-on-htc-sense

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you the advise to get completely independent from the TabWidget and create your own Navigation, which you can customize however you want and don't bother with the stiff TabWidget. I don't mean to throw away the awesome TabHost, because it's easy to use the TabHost with a custom navigation:

First set your TabWidget as gone:

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

And then create you own navigation in place of it. You could also create a menu (with the hardware menu button) or something like this:

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <!-- content of your tabs-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/slider_stub"
            android:background="@color/overview_banner_bg_down"/>
        <!-- custom slider with horizontal scrollable radio buttons-->
        <com.example.WrappingSlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/tab_slider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:handle="@+id/tab_slider_handle"
            android:content="@+id/tab_scroller">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_slider_handle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/def_slider">
            </RelativeLayout>
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/tab_scroller"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_track"
                android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_thumb"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbarSize="3dip"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="80dp"
                android:background="#343534">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/custom_tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:checkedButton="@+id/tab_overview">
                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/tab_overview"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:background="@drawable/def_checktab_overview"/>
                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/tab_news"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:background="@drawable/def_checktab_news"/>
                            .....etc....your tabs......
                    </RadioGroup>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </com.example.WrappingSlidingDrawer>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

What you have to do in code now:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_tab_layout);

    setTabs();

    RadioGroup tabs = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_tabs);

    tabs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.tab_overview:
                getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);
                break;
            case R.id.tab_news:
                getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
                break;
            ....etc.....
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Delegate tab creation and adding.
 */
private void setTabs() {
    // add the necessary tabs
    addTab(R.string.tab_overv_tag, OverviewActivityGroup.class);
    addTab(R.string.tab_news_tag, NewsActivityGroup.class);
            .....etc.....
}

/**
 * Create a tab with an Activity and add it to the TabHost
 *  
 * @param tagId
 *            resource id of the string representing the tag for finding the tab    
 * @param activity
 *            the activity to be added
 */
private void addTab(int tagId, Class<? extends ActivityGroup> activity) {
    // create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, activity);
    // initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = usedTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(tagId));
    // use layout inflater to get a view of the tab to be added
    View tabIndicator = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    usedTabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

The whole indicator stuff is not needed btw.^^ In your ActivityGroups you have to set the appropriate Activities, etc. You know the stuff.

You can use anything for your navigation and can still use the advantages of a TabHost. Just don't bother with that TabWidget anymore. ;)

Answer (score 1):

After some research I think the best option would be to use ActionBar's tabbed interface since it looks much more easier to style. The [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) provides compatibility layer for ActionBar for devices starting from Android 1.6. [Here you can look at examples](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html) on what you can get using the library.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is awesome and I'm also using it, so I recommend this solution. :-)