# Android tab layout example required

Tags: android, layout, tabs

I'm looking for an example, like the standard "Tab Layout" tutorial that uses BOTH activities for each tab and a dedicated xml layout file for each tab.

Can anyone help. All the examples I've found simply use the following for the layout

```
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
textview.setText("This is the Artists tab");
setContentView(textview);
```

The reason for using activities is that for one of the tabs I want to force a landscape orientation.

Comment: this tutorial might help you http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/how-to-use-tabwidget-with-fragments/

Answer (score 1):

Try here:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1

If you need any help with this let me know because I have a fully customized TabHost in my APP's.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Tab Layout Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) shows how to use separate activities for each tab's content. Just combine it with the following code snippet:

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("layout tab")
   .setIndicator("Layout based tab")
   .setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
      public View createTabContent (String tag) {
         return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_tab, null);
      }
});

tabHost.addTab(spec);

Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("activity tab")
   .setIndicator("Activity based tab")
   .setContent(intent);

tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Looking for a universal TabHost style that will work on Android, HTC Sense, Samsung, etc. skins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156116/looking-for-a-universal-tabhost-style-that-will-work-on-android-htc-sense-samsu)

In addition to that in your ActivityGroup:

```
public class YourActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {

private List<View> viewCache;

public void replaceView(View view) {
    if (viewCache == null) {
        viewCache = new ArrayList<View>();
    }
    viewCache.add(view);
    setContentView(view);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup
    replaceView(startYourActivity());
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // handling rotation
    resetCache();

    // reset the ui
    replaceView(startYourActivity());
}

private View startYourActivity() {
    // Start the root activity withing the group and get its view
    return getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(YourActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
            new Intent(this, YourActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
}

/**
 * Clears the View cache.
 */
public void resetCache() {
    viewCache = new ArrayList<View>();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.back();
}

}
```

Rest is easy.^^